# ngClass not getting applied

Tags: angular

I have to apply a css style to an input depending on a var value

**HTML**

```
 <input class="defaultInput" [ngClass]="{'inputerror':'emptyFields'}" formControlName="idAnnuaire" placeholder="Ex: c20011">
```

**CSS**

```
.inputerror {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Emtyfields is well changed from false to true but the ``.inputerror` is not applied to input

Comment: can you post the image of input from source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `emptyFields` property without the single quotes i.e. **`[ngClass]="{'inputerror':emptyFields}"`**.

Change your template code to following:

```
<input class="defaultInput" 
       [ngClass]="{'inputerror':emptyFields}"
       formControlName="idAnnuaire" 
       placeholder="Ex: c20011">
```

Answer (score 1):

`emptyFields` has to be a variable , you have mentioned as a string.

```
<input class="defaultInput" [ngClass]="{'inputerror':emptyFields}" formControlName="idAnnuaire" placeholder="Ex: c20011">
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w67jpn)

I have removed the formContrlName for now